# Why did the Architect need to make the Will to destroy the House and all of Creation instead of just destroying it herself?

Tags: keys-to-the-kingdom

In Garth Nix's Keys to the Kingdom, The Architect divided herself into The Old One and The Will, and entrusted The Will to be carried out by her Trustees.

But considering the whole point of The Will was to destroy all of creation, why did she have to make it so complicated? Why couldn't She just do it herself?

Comment: I'll write a full answer later, but, long story short, first, the Old One/Architect split happened long before the Will. Second, the Will was a way for the Architect to withdraw somewhat from the universe while the Trustees administered things, made preparations.

Comment: @Adamant Waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There were things to put in order before (or after) she died.

…**that’s why it’s a Will**.

First, the split between the Architect and the Old One happened long before the breaking of the Will, and was not related to it. This split enabled the Architect to speed up the process of creating the universe.

> More than fifteen billion years ago, as mortals count time, I made the
>   stars and waited while planets were born. I watched as life began. But
>   it was slow, so slow, even for such as I…I thought to intervene, and
>   chose to separate part of my nature, to create a related entity who
>   would oversee this work. So it was I made the Old One from myself.
>
> <sub>*Lord Sunday*</sub>

Undoubtedly the Architect would be well capable of opening the House to Nothing and letting it be destroyed. However, there were things to be done:

> I could not release the Old One and so free myself, without destroying
>   everything I had made, the House and all the Universe beyond. So I
>   began that process of destruction with the fracture of myself and the
>   making of the Will.
>
> It should have been quickly executed, but the Trustees had grown
>   disobedient and they would not perform the actions that would lead to
>   their own demise. Yet they could not entirely resist the powers of my
>   Will. In time it twisted their natures…and so unwittingly they came to
>   work to my desired end.
>
> <sub>*Lord Sunday*</sub>

One of those things, it is implied, is choosing a New Architect from among the ranks of mortals to create a new universe:

> As the old Universe is destroyed, a new one is made. You will make it.
>
> <sub>*Lord Sunday*</sub>

The Architect’s wording clearly implies that this was part of her plan from the beginning, and that simply choosing from among the ranks of her Denizens would be insufficient.

> No. It had to be a mortal, someone who can create. Denizens were made
>   directly by me and can only copy. I made the basic stuff from which
>   you mortals evolved, Arthur, with some tinkering here and there, but I
>   did not make you directly…and you mortals surpass even Us with your
>   ideas.
>
> <sub>*Lord Sunday*</sub>

It should be clear that the process of finding a suitable mortal, getting them to the point where they could be a good replacement, deciding what to do with the current universe, and so forth, could, under ideal conditions, take some time. Keep in mind than when the Architect says that the Will should have been carried out “quickly,” she’s speaking as someone who is about 15 billion years old.

As to why the Architect created a Will to carry out these tasks, I think we can only speculate, but we have a pretty good guess. She wanted to die, and fracturing herself into several components was basically the best she could do while the universe still existed. It’s difficult to say to what degree her “overall” consciousness continued to exist in some form while she was split into the Will (or indeed while the Architect-as-Primus and the Old one were separate), though the Old One and Will’s unity of purpose in their destruction suggests it did in some fashion. If it ceased to exist altogether, perhaps one could even say that the Architect did die, after a fashion.

But either way, it wouldn’t be all that far from dying, and so it would be very attractive for the Architect to do this to herself while she awaited a fuller and more permanent dissolution. With a piece of herself to guide each trustee in setting the House in order and choosing an Heir, what could go wrong…?

---

And yes, the Will is a pun. It’s the Will of the Architect, the [Will of God.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_of_God) But it’s also her will and testament to be executed both before and after her death (or purely after, depending on how one looks at things).